# What is the quickest and most efficient way of testing one array of items against another and then sorting the matches in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, google-apps-script

I have recently created a script which looks at one spreadsheet and creates a list of items we want. Then it looks for those items in another spreadsheet and creates an array of objects of the matches. Then the objects are sorted by their name property. Finally they're outputted on a different sheet but that's irrelevant here.

What is the best way of doing this in JS? Are there more efficient ways than the ones I've used (i'm sure there are).

```
    //get basic information about the spreadsheet

var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
var rows = new Array();
var numRows = new Array();


for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    rows[i] = sheets[i].getDataRange();
    numRows[i] = rows[i].getNumRows();
}


//Create an object for each company with suppressed and total statements variables
//object will have properties name, supressed integer, total integer, and a percentage calculated through a percentage() method
function companySupressionStat(name, supressed, total) {
    this.name = name;
    this.supressed = supressed;
    this.total = total;



}
var objectNames = new Array();
// find the column with the supression data
function findSupression() {
    var supressedColumn;

    // check every column on the 3rd row for the word supressed column
    for (var l = 1; l < sheets[1].getLastColumn(); l++) {

        if (sheets[1].getRange(3, l).getValue() == "Supr.ed Stmts") {
            supressedColumn = l;
            break;
        }
    }

    return supressedColumn;

}

//find company name column

function findCompany() {
    var companyColumn;

    for (var l = 1; l < sheets[1].getLastColumn(); l++) {
        if (sheets[1].getRange(1, l).getValue() == "SLA Legend") {
            companyColumn = l;
            break;
        }
    }
    return companyColumn;

}
// check if we have missing value, then identify them in an array of strings called listErrors
function listErrorChecker(listLength, objectLength, objectNames, list) {
    var listErrors = new Array(); // create a variable to keep track of our missing company's
    if (listLength > objectLength) { //if our list is longer than our array of objects

        for (var l = 0; l < list.length; l++) {
            Logger.log(objectNames.indexOf(list[l]));
            if (objectNames.indexOf(list[l]) == -1) {
                listErrors.push("The company " + list[l] + " is missing from our output! Please check the spelling and case of " + list[l].toUpperCase() + " and make sure it is the same as the report we are looking in.");
            }
        }
        return listErrors;
    }
    else {
        listErrors = "no errors";
        return listErrors;
    }

}

//Create an array list of all the company's we want to track

var list = new Array();
for (var k = 1; k <= numRows[0]; k++) {
    list.push(sheets[0].getRange(k, 1).getValue().toLowerCase()); //assumes that our list is in our first spreadsheet, in the first column

}

//Go down the spreadsheet on the column w/ the word "suppression". start creating new objects with the the correct properties if the company name is on our list of company names.


var arrayOfObjects = new Array();
var companyColumn = findCompany();
var supressedColumn = findSupression();
var lastRow = sheets[1].getLastRow();

for (var m = 1; m <= lastRow; m++) {
    if (sheets[1].getRange(m, companyColumn).getValue() !== "" && list.indexOf(sheets[1].getRange(m, companyColumn).getValue().toLowerCase()) !== -1) { //if the company name is not blank and if the company name is in our list, create a new instance of the compression stat object
        arrayOfObjects.push(new companySupressionStat(
        sheets[1].getRange(m, companyColumn).getValue(),
        sheets[1].getRange(m, supressedColumn).getValue(),
        sheets[1].getRange(m, supressedColumn + 2).getValue()));
        objectNames.push(sheets[1].getRange(m, companyColumn).getValue().toLowerCase()); //keep track of the object's names in a simple arrray of strings for error checking later
    }
}

// sort our array of objects by name of company alphabetically
function sortOn(property) {
    return function(a, b) {
        if (a[property] < b[property]) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (a[property] > b[property]) {
            return 1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    };
}


arrayOfObjects.sort(sortOn("name")); // call the sorting function
```

Comment: If you are asking how to optimize code which is currently working, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Look as some of the existing performance tests here: http://jsperf.com/

Comment: is it really taking longer than needed?

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely change list and objectNames lists to objects, and then I would use object properties (like a HashSet in C#) .

For example, I would change list as:

```
var list = {};
for (var k = 1; k <= numRows[0]; k++) {
    list[sheets[0].getRange(k, 1).getValue().toLowerCase()]=1;
}
....
....
....
for (var m = 1; m <= lastRow; m++) {
    if (sheets[1].getRange(m, companyColumn).getValue() !== "" && list[sheets[1].getRange(m, companyColumn).getValue().toLowerCase()]) {
```

Generaly searching an array is slower than looking up object properties.

See it here: [Array Performance](http://jsperf.com/array-vs-object-performance)